# How to see the highest value between two columns of a dataframe and how many values in one column are greater than the other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to compare two columns (a, b) of a dataframe to see how many values of "a" are greater than "b in Pandas.

I've tried this way but I don't know if it's the best option:

```
def result(y,z):
    if(y > z):
          return True

df_filtered.apply(lambda y: result(y['a'],y['b']), axis = 1)
```

This shows me as a result a list of true and false results, but I would need to know the amount of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `value_counts`

```
df['a'].gt(df['b']).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
(df['a'] > df['b']).sum()
```

Consider following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[10,20,30,40],
    'b':[1,200,300,4]
})
```

Output:

```
    a   b
0   10  1
1   20  200
2   30  300
3   40  4
```

Then

```
 (df['a'] > df['b']).sum()
```

Output

```
2
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked for the larger numbers, when I try to see the smaller ones, it brings me an incorrect amount:
 (df['a'] > df['b']).sum()
Output:
7980

(df['b'] > df['a']).sum()
Output:
73

But the total number of rows is 11975 and the fields are not empty.

Comment: Is it possible that you have 3922 rows where `a` and `b` have equal numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You did it right, simply add the value_counts() such that:

```
df_filtered.apply(lambda y: result(y['a'],y['b']), axis = 1).value_counts()
```

better yet, if your function *result* is trivial you can write:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['a']>x['b'], axis=1).value_counts()
```